# ngFor doesn't print JSON data

Tags: json, angular

I'm developing an Angular2 application and I want to display some JSON data with http GET request from a JSON file.
Here's my JSON (file data/contatti.json):

```
[
    "08823323459", 
    "3325849593",
    "somemail@hotmail.com"
]
```

I have a ContactService that requests data from this file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ContattiService {

private contactUrl = 'data/contatti.json';
constructor(private http: Http) { }

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

getContatti(): Promise<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.contactUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as string[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
}
```

There is a component that retrieves the data using the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { ContattiService } from './contatti.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'contact-app',
    templateUrl: './contatti.html'
})

export class ContactComponent {

contatti: string[];
constructor(
    private contactService: ContattiService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getContatti();
}

getContatti(): void {
    this.contactService.getContatti().then(contatti => this.contatti = contatti);
}
}
```

But when I try to display them in my html page (contatti.html):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let contatto of contatti">
                    {{contatto}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

The page doesn't print data. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-quotes from the .json file?

Comment: Sorry, it was a writing question mistake. They don't appear in my code.

Comment: Is missing `*` before ngFor a mistake either?

Comment: No @Sergey Mell, I tried with *ngFor but no data was displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite you method with subscribe:

```
getContatti(): void {
    this.contactService.getContatti()
     .subscribe(contatti => this.contatti = contatti);
}
```

and service to:

```
getContatti(): {
    return this.http.get(this.contactUrl)
        .map(res => res.json().data)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }
```

And one more, if you try to access res.json().data your contatti.json should look like:

```
{
  "data": [
    "08823323459", 
    "3325849593",
    "somemail@hotmail.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes Korotkikh, your solution works! Thank you so much!

Comment: To be honest, it was only necessary to change the JSON file like you suggest to make my code work ! :)

Comment: Yeah, you right ;) I simply forgot when I last time use promises in angular )

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the component,

```
getContatti(): void {
    this.contactService.getContatti().subscribe(contatti=>{
      this.contatti = contatti;
    });
}
```

and service.ts should be,

```
getContatti(): {
    return this.http.get(this.contactUrl)
        .map(res => res.json().data)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan, but I don't understand what should be this.newService in your code.

Comment: it should be contactService